# Undeclared views in UIScrollView with multiple nibs

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, addsubview

I'm trying to render 3 different views in the same UIScrollView using 3 nibs. But xcode keeps giving back the error that the views are undeclared

```
- (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];
    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scroll.pagingEnabled = YES;
    NSInteger numberOfViews = 3;


    MainWindow.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [scroll addSubview:MainWindow.view];
    view2.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [scroll addSubview:view2.view];
    view3.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width*2, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [scroll addSubview:view3.view];

    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:scroll];
    [scroll release];
}
```

In this example Xcode would say MainWindow, view2 and view 3 are undeclared. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the MainWindow, view2 and view3? From the above snippet it's hard to deduce what's worng.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare an object by

```
NSObject *object
```

Do you may wish to do

```
UIView *view2 = ...
```

to declare and define `view2`

Comment: This gives me new error: "error: request for member 'view' in something not a structure or union." So my problem probably lies beyond the declaration of the objects.

Comment: It seems that view2 is/should be a view controller, not a view